# When should I unsubscribe from observables in activities and fragments to avoid negative consequences?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have subscribers that interact with UI components of an activity/fragment. I'm not sure where and when should I unsubscribe them. I see two ways: the former is to unsubscribe them in the onPause() method, the latter is to unsubscribe them in the onStop() method. Which one is correct and why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onPause` as you don't need the listener running while the activity or fragment is not. `onPause` gets called everytime the item is no longer activity running. `onStop` is called on the way to destruction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if my observable downloads some content after the activity starts, I will lose the content if I get an SMS message in a popup window or someone calls me. And I will need to re-download the content

Comment: `onStop` is also called when the UI of the component is no longer visible, but not being destroyed either.

Comment: @Buckstabue - sounds like you need a Presenter component that does not get destroyed when different instances of your `Activity` get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

*"But what if my observable downloads some content after the activity starts"*
For long time operations or operations that must be independent from Activity Lifecycle you shuold use [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Service.html) component

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle. It will prevent your app from throwing NPE on views and context memory leaks.
Read about MVP pattern. Below I made exemplary implementation

Presenter class

```
public class SamplePresenter {

    @NonNull
    private final Observable<SomeData> someDataObservable;

    public SamplePresenter(@NonNull ApiService apiService) {

        someDataObservable = apiService.apiRequest()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    @NonNull
    public Observable<SomeData> getSomeDataObservable() {
        return someDataObservable;
    }
}
```

MainActivity class

```
@Inject
SamplePresenter samplePresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    samplePresenter.getSomeDataObservable()
            .compose(this.<SomeData>bindToLifecycle())
            .subscribe(new Action1<SomeData>() {
                @Override
                public void call(SomeData someData) {

                }
            });
```